# Add text-list to hyperlink cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macro-recorder

How can I add text from column A to page link in column B?
So I would like to scrap part of page from hundreds of page, and I need to put text data on column A to ...com/[text from column A]. Maybe someone have a formula.

I've tried using Macro features, but didn't know how to loop my Macro using script editor. You can see the Macro script below.

[image: My Worksheet]

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Untitledmacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('https://www.example.com/AHAP')
  .setTextStyle(0, 34, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#1155cc')
  .setUnderline(true)
  .build())
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('https://www.example.com/AIMS')
  .setTextStyle(0, 34, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#1155cc')
  .setUnderline(true)
  .build())
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('B6').activate();
};

function Untitledmacro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('https://www.example.com/AISA')
  .setTextStyle(0, 34, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#1155cc')
  .setUnderline(true)
  .build())
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('https://www.example.com/AKKU')
  .setTextStyle(0, 34, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#1155cc')
  .setUnderline(true)
  .build())
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
};
```

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73394147/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Formula option:**

1. If you have text in column A and links in column B, you can use the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(B1:B,A1:A))`

****With Google AppsScript:****

1. If the link will be the same for all rows and you have text in column A, you can use the following script:

```
function makeLinks1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');///Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  let rangeWord = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  let link =  'https://www.example.com/';

  rangeWord = rangeWord.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});

  for (let i=0; i< rangeWord.length ; i++){
    ss.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(link+rangeWord[i]);
  };
}
```

2. If you have text in column A and links from column B are different, you can run the following script:

```
function makeLinks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); ///Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  let rangeWord = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  let rangeLinks = ss.getRange("B1:B").getValues().flat();

  rangeWord = rangeWord.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});
  rangeLinks = rangeLinks.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});

  for (let i=0; i< rangeWord.length ; i++){
    ss.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(rangeLinks[i]+rangeWord[i]);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function makelinks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const shsr = 4;
  const url = "http://www.example.com/";
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1,2).getValues();
  let vo = vs.map((r,i) => {
    return [`=HYPERLINK("${url}${r[0]}","${r[0]}")`];
  });
  sh.getRange(shsr,2,vo.length,vo[0].length).setFormulas(vo);
}
```